# Auto-fill full name of person according to the existing names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibrNa.png)

I want Google Sheet to give me the option to auto-fill from existing people's names in the same google sheet while I start typing the first few letters of person's name. Example picture is above. How can I do this?

Comment: You might be able to do that with onedit but I think it would be clumnsy

Comment: There is no trigger that can respond to keystrokes as you are typing.  Only onEdit and onChange that require the user to leave the cell to trigger the event.

Comment: Is this a programming question? It sounds like something for the Google forums.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets have auto-fill with dropdown lists. It doesn't look like what you want, but it solves your problem.

[Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)